# Linq2Sql creates an extra instance when I change the value of a property - why?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table called UserProperties. There is a small set of user properties for each user. I load them up into the program into a Dictionary called **_userProperties** (so that they are cashed).

Basicly the table looks like this:

[image: User Properties Table]

The columns: CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, CreatedBy and ModifiedBy are not part of the DAL (dbml) as they are strictly for debugging purpuses. A trigger sets ModifiedBy and ModifiedOn.

When the user wants to save his settings (or the program thinks they should be saved) I call this code:

```
 string userPropertyValueAsString = (String)Convert.ChangeType(userPropertyValue, typeof(String));
 if (_userProperties.ContainsKey(userPropertyKey))
 {
     if (_userProperties[userPropertyKey] != userPropertyValueAsString)
     {
        using (DataAccessDataContext dataContext = CreateContext(JsApplication.CommitDal))
        {
(1)         UserProperty changedUserProperty = dataContext.UserProperties.First(u => u.fk_Employee == employeeId && u.PropertyName == userPropertyKey);
(2)         changedUserProperty.PropertyValue = userPropertyValueAsString;
            _userProperties[userPropertyKey] = changedUserProperty.PropertyValue;
            if (!dataContext.SubmitChanges())
            {
                throw new SubmitChangesException(employeeId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I reach (1) the constructor of class UserProperty gets called (as expected since a UserProperty is found in the table at the database). But when I reach (2) the constructor is called again, which creates a second instance and this has me baffled.

No exception gets thrown and the extra instance gets saved to the table (which cause a bug because the extra instance contains the changes propertyvalue and the next time the old value gets read from the database through the row with the smaller id (the old one)).

The callstack looks like this (I put a breakpoint into the constructor and captured the screendumb right after (2):

[image: Call stack just after (2)]

**Could anyone please tell me why WPF does this and how I make it stop?**

Windows: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit
Visual Studio: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: There is a clustered index on: fk_Employee (ASC), PropertyName (ASC), IsDeleted (DESC). And (of cause) id is primary key.

Comment: One obvious way to fix it is to set `_UserProperties[UserPropertyKey] = userPropertyValueAsString` instead.

Comment: I need to get the data saved to the database. That statement will only change the cashed data (the dictionary). Actually I do this in the statement right after (2)

Comment: `changedUserProperty.PropertyValue = userPropertyValueAsString` will save the data to the database.  `_UserProperties[UserPropertyKey] = userPropertyValueAsString` will save the data to the cache.

Comment: I fail to see your point. You are correct about what saves to the database and what saves to the cache. I need both - but saving to the database gives me an extra copy of the UserProperty which is my problem. Not saving to the database is not solving my problem (that is how I understod your solution)

Comment: Sorry, I was reading the line below (2).  See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Linq to SQL code seems a bit unorthodox, so I offer the following alternate code below.  Note the use of a DataContext member variable, a constructor, and `FirstOrDefault` with a null check instead of `First()`.  The function returns `true` if it succeeds, `false` if it does not.  Although the Linq DataContext implements `Dispose`, it is better to simply let it go out of scope (you can find documentation for this elsewhere on the Internet).

```
public class UserSettings
{
     DataAccessDataContext dc;
     bool result = false;
     string[] _userProperties;

     public Settings(JSApplication application, string[] userProperties)
     {
         dataContext = CreateContext(application.CommitDal));
         _userProperties = userProperties;
     }

     public bool SaveUserSettings(string key, string settings)
     { 
         var property = dc.UserProperties.FirstOrDefault(u => u.fk_Employee == employeeId && u.PropertyName == userPropertyKey);
         if (property != null)
         {
              property.Value = settings;
              _userProperties[key] = settings;
              result = dc.SubmitChanges();
         }
         return result;
     }
}
```